# How to receive NSNotifications from Objective-C in C++ classes?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++, nsnotifications

I have an Objective-C++ class that adds itself as an observer for an event on a Cocoa NSView. I would like to be able to send the NSNotifications to a method of a C++ class instead of an Objective-C method or block. How can I do this?

My situation is this:

- A - Objective-C++ class
- B - NSView

B is encapsulated by A. I want to be notified of one of B's events. However, the method handling that event MUST have a reference to the instance of A that contains B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dead simple wrapper class in Objective-C that points to your C++ instance and handles the notification by calling the C++ method.

Comment: D'oh. I actually just realized I could do this about 10 minutes ago. Thanks for your answer though. Simple, precise and to the point. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not consume the notification with a C++ method directly, or simple C function for that matter.

You must wrap the call to the C++ method is an actual Objective-C method, or block, and then delegate forward the notification to the C++ method.